# Codeigniter 2.0 GET params with URI rounting

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

Hey, 
I've wrote a line in my routes.php as the following:

```
$route['admin/trip/add'] = "admin/trip_controller/form";
```

But when I go to that URL in my browser, I get sent back to the main index page i.e (www.mydomain.com), does anybody know what i'm doing wrong?

I've enabled GET params in my config file too:

```
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings']   = TRUE;
```

I've also tried going to a URL which doesnt use routing and I too get redirected back to the main index page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enable_query_strings is a configuration option that will allow you to send your controller and method via ?c=blog&m=view. This will cause trouble because obviously you aren't sending those in your query string, so CodeIgniter will assume nothing is passed and display the homepage.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your answer, ive set enable_query_strings to false however it doenst make any difference :-/ any more suggestions?

Comment: Play around with the $config['uri_protocol'] to try out the various options. Different servers need to use different protocols.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to use the _remap() function instead of messing with the routes.

So I guess you would have the admin.php controller.

Inside you would use the remap function which will use the second segment of the url to find what function to call.

```
<?php

class Admin extends Controller{


function _remap($method, $params =array())
{
  if(method_exists($method))
  {
   $this->$method(); 
  }
  elseif($method == 'trip' && $this->uri->segment(3)=='add')
  {
   //do what you want here
  }
}
```

Comment: huh? I want to use routes so that I can have the URI that I want and also I dont want to define this remap function in every controller :-/